# symfony ux-autocomplete functional test case symfony php unit

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete, phpunit, functional-testing

I've implemented [symfony ux autocomplete](https://github.com/symfony/ux-autocomplete) with ajax loading. Which is working 100%.

When you implement it using ajax it loads nothing in the select dropdown unless you search and it will show the desired solutions.

Currently, I'm facing an issue in writing the test case for this below is my test case for the controller and formType:

```
    public function testNewStockRequestTool(): void
    {
        $this->client->loginUser($this->user);
        $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_POST, '/stock/tool/new');
        $this->client->submitForm('Save', [
            'stock_request_tool[tool][autocomplete]' => $this->stockRequestTool->getTool()->getId(),
            'stock_request_tool[quantity]' => 20,
        ]);

        self::assertResponseRedirects('/stock/request/');
    }
```

It throws the below error:

```
InvalidArgumentException : Input "stock_request_tool[tool][autocomplete]" cannot take "cb9ec75c-a1c4-5bf6-a533-9d5e154dbe86" as a value (possible values: "").
```

This makes sense because the ChoiceFormType does not contain any option when it is implemented using AJAX because no data is loaded as it is loaded on the run time when you search in the select box.

**My question is how can I fix this functional test case to make it work? Is there some way to search in the select list and it should populate the ChoiceType with those options and after that, I can pass that value as I'm doing currently?**

Answer (score 0):

You can test it by adding `<option>` element before submitting form just like below:

```
  public function testNewStockRequestTool(): void
  {
      $this->client->loginUser($this->user);
-     $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_POST, '/stock/tool/new');
+     $crawler = $this->client->request(Request::METHOD_POST, '/stock/tool/new');
+ 
+     $domDocument = $crawler->getNode(0)?->parentNode;
+     $option = $domDocument->createElement('option');
+     $option->setAttribute('value', $this->stockRequestTool->getTool()->getId());
+     $crawler->filter('select#stock_request_tool_tool_autocomplete')->getNode(0)?->appendChild($option);
+ 
      $this->client->submitForm('Save', [
          'stock_request_tool[tool][autocomplete]' => $this->stockRequestTool->getTool()->getId(),
          'stock_request_tool[quantity]' => 20,
      ]);
  
      self::assertResponseRedirects('/stock/request/');
  }
```